# R: Extract value and lines after key word (text file mining)

Tags: r, keyword, text-mining

Setting:
I have (simple) .csv and .dat files created from laboratory devices and other programs storing information on measurements or calculations. I have found this for other languages but nor for R

Problem:
Using R, I am trying to extract values to quickly display results w/o opening the created files. Hereby I have two typical settings:

a) I need to read a priori unknown values after known key words
b) I need to read lines after known key words or lines

I can't make functions such as scan() and grep() work.

c) Finally I would like to loop over dozens of files in a folder and give me a summary (to make the picture complete: I will manage this part)

I woul appreciate any form of help.

Comment: What did you try with `grep` and `scan` that didn't work (`grepl` may be a better choice here)?

Comment: ok, it works for the key value (although perhaps not very nice)

     variable<-scan("file.csv", what=character(),sep="")

returns a charactor vector

      variable[grep("keyword", ks)+2]     # + 2 as the actual value 
is stored two places ahead

returns characters of seaked values.

     as.numeric(lapply(variable, gsub, patt=",", replace="."))

for completion: data had to be altered to number and "," and "."
 problem needed to be solved.
in a line:
     data=as.numeric(lapply(ks[grep("Ks_Boden", ks)+2], gsub, patt=",", replace="."))
that does it

Comment: sorry about the long string ^.-

Comment: If I understand you correctly you've solve your own problem.  You can add your response as an answer and accept it so future searchers can benefit from your struggle ;-)

Comment: thank you for the reminder, i am reasonably new so I have to wait 8 hours before doing so ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, it works for the key value (although perhaps not very nice)

```
 variable<-scan("file.csv", what=character(),sep="")
```

returns a charactor vector of everything

```
 variable[grep("keyword", ks)+2]     # + 2 as the actual value is stored two places ahead
```

returns characters of seaked values.

```
 as.numeric(lapply(variable, gsub, patt=",", replace="."))
```

for completion: data had to be altered to number and "," and "." problem needed to be solved.

in a line:
     data=as.numeric(lapply(ks[grep("Ks_Boden", ks)+2], gsub, patt=",", replace="."))

Perseverence is not to bad of an asset ;-)

The rest isn't finished, yet, I will post once finished.